# Pass NSObject in CFNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications

How can I pass a NSObject to another class using CFNotifications? I need to use CFNotifications for what I'm trying to do, so NSNotifications will not work.

I thought about converting a NSObject to a kind of CFString id of that object, and then recreating the NSObject on the other process (that receives the CFNotification) with that CFString, but I have no idea on how to do that.

Please help,

Pedro Franceschi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `CFNotificationCenterPostNotification` you can do this:

```
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// SOMEWHERE IN A FUNCTION OR METHOD:
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

id object = /* Assume this exists */;
CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(aCenter, CFSTR("NotificationName"), (__bridge void *) object, NULL, true);

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// LATER IN YOUR CODE:
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

void receivedNotification(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    id object = (__bridge id) object;
    /* Do stuff with `object`. */
}
```

*Leave out the `__bridge`s if you're not using ARC.*

Comment: I've tried in other code and now I got "‘__bridge’ was not declared in this scope"... Why?

Comment: I'm trying to compile that code on iPhone now... It needs to use CFNotifications too.

Comment: I tried without the __bridge, and it didn't work. The object is (null) in the process I'm receiving the CFNotification, and when I'm posting the notification, the object is not null.

Comment: Probably because the object is released before the notification is received. You'll need to find some way to keep that object alive while you're still receiving the notification. Maybe you could `retain` the object before adding the observer and then `release` it before you remove the observer>

Comment: I tried retainig the object, and even with a NSString retained, it didn't work. The object is null in the side I'm receiving the notification. Any other ideas?